# JerseyTest Client with MessageBodyWriter don't pass headers to my MessageBodyReader server-side

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-test-framework

My headers are not correctly passed from client to server when using `JerseyTest`.

Both server and client have `MessageBodyWriter` and `MessageBodyReader` configured respectively with `JerseyTest::configure` and `JerseyTest::configureClient`.

My `MessageBodyWriter` add some custom headers to query :

```
@Override
public void writeTo(MyPojo myPojo, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
    httpHeaders.put("X-Custom-Header", singletonList(myPojo.header()));
}
```

but when `MessageBodyReader` is hit by server, it contains only standard headers.

Any clues on what I'm missing ?

Comment: Did you [register the writer with the client](https://gist.github.com/psamsotha/3c44023743812377fcc5#file-headerstest-java-L112). It won't be picked up on the client side with a `@Provider` annotation like it does on the server.

Comment: Actually reading your question again, it looks like you did override the configureClient. Are you using the client provided by the `target()` method, or are you creating the own `Client`? In any case, the link above has a working example

Comment: thx for your help
but with 2.22.1 version of Jersey your gist fail
    `Expected :header:entity`
    `Actual   :null:entity`

Comment: That's actually the version I'm testing with

Comment: ok so something seeems interfering on my side

Comment: I use Jetty as a container it's your case also ?

Comment: Do you see the header in the log? With the logging filter registered, you should see all the headers. I just confirmed that it's in my logs

Comment: sorry put code in comment is not really viewable
but no i don't see the header in request server-side

Comment: Let me try with Jetty and see what happens

Comment: Works fine for me with Jetty container also

Comment: seems a bug in `InMemoryConnector`

Comment: You're right. I just reproduced the problem with the in-memory provider. [Using a filter works though](https://gist.github.com/psamsotha/1f24b9e89c685d092bfb#file-headerinfiltertest-java-L95)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok seems a bug with `InMemoryConnector` :

```
public ClientResponse apply(final ClientRequest clientRequest) {
    PropertiesDelegate propertiesDelegate = new MapPropertiesDelegate();

    final ContainerRequest containerRequest = new ContainerRequest(baseUri,
            clientRequest.getUri(), clientRequest.getMethod(),
            null, propertiesDelegate);

    containerRequest.getHeaders().putAll(clientRequest.getStringHeaders());

    final ByteArrayOutputStream clientOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    if (clientRequest.getEntity() != null) {
        clientRequest.setStreamProvider(new OutboundMessageContext.StreamProvider() {
            @Override
            public OutputStream getOutputStream(int contentLength) throws IOException {
                final MultivaluedMap<String, Object> clientHeaders = clientRequest.getHeaders();
                if (contentLength != -1 && !clientHeaders.containsKey(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH)) {
                    containerRequest.getHeaders().putSingle(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, String.valueOf(contentLength));
                }
                return clientOutput;
            }
        });
```

All standard headers are set with :

`containerRequest.getHeaders().putAll(clientRequest.getStringHeaders());`

But if you provide custom headers, they are read but never added to `containerRequest` :

`final MultivaluedMap<String, Object> clientHeaders = clientRequest.getHeaders();`

also https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2341 suggest it won't be fixed soon.